# Trying to open a link from Alert dialog,but it's not working. Don,t know why?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

```
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Visit MOMA", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            Uri web_page = Uri.parse(URL);
                            Intent baseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, web_page);
                            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(baseIntent,"Open "+URL+" with:");
                            Log.i(TAG,"Chooser Intent Action:" + chooserIntent.getAction());
                            if(baseIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
                                Log.i(TAG,"Chooser Intent Action22:" + chooserIntent.getAction());
                                startActivity(chooserIntent);
                            }


                        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

//You can use this

//A sample code for open dialog is as follows

```
public class DandGDialogActivity  extends DialogFragment{

    private View mViewHolder;
    private EditText etHeight,etWeight,etHC;
    private TextView tvDate;
    //private SystemAppPreferences mSysAppPrefs;

    public static DandGDialogActivity  getInstance() {
        DandGDialogActivity fragment = new DandGDialogActivity ();
        return fragment;
    }



    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //  mSysAppPrefs = SystemAppPreferences.getInstance(getActivity());

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);

        builder.setCancelable(false);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        mViewHolder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vitals, null);
        etHeight=(EditText) mViewHolder.findViewById(R.id.editTextheight);
        etWeight=(EditText) mViewHolder.findViewById(R.id.editTextweight);
        etHC=(EditText) mViewHolder.findViewById(R.id.editTexthc);
        tvDate=(TextView) mViewHolder.findViewById(R.id.textViewdate);
        tvDate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date()));



        tvDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Calendar mdate=Calendar.getInstance();
                int year=mdate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int monthOfYear=mdate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int dayOfMonth=mdate.get(Calendar.DATE);
                        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                        // Display Selected date in textbox
                                       tvDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                                + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                                    }
                                },  year, monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);

                            dpd.show();
                            dpd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        }
                    });


        //builder.setTitle("Admin Login");
        mViewHolder.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        builder.setView(mViewHolder)

                .setPositiveButton("Save",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                if (etHeight.length() == 0||etWeight.length()==0||etHC.length()==0) {

                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                            " Please enter all field Properly ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                    return;


                                }

                                else {

                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                            " All feilds are ok ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                    dismiss();
                                }


                            }
                        })

                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dismiss();
                            }
                        });
        return builder.create();
    }
```

}

//To call the dialog you have to use the following code

```
alertdialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
```